# Job applications: Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, bug-reporting-process

I don't know where to report this. But it's been more than a week now, I can't see my job applications. It says at the end of the message that I can report it in meta.
[image: stack overflow bug in job applications]

Answer (score 1):

You know how, when you're working through scenarios and you come up with a strange edge case that's tough to handle, and the group decides "oh, that could *never* happen", so you save the performance cost of dealing with that edge case.... well, that thing that could *never* happen did for you and a few other people as part of the Application History feature we rolled out Monday of this week.

But, the fix for it is going out right now. You shouldn't see the sad robot anymore.

Comment: What was that edge case?

Comment: Multiple applications against a job posting "slot" that was used for both a job entirely handled within the SO Talent system (ie: you apply for the job entirely at stackoverflow.com/jobs) and was also used for a job handled by an external system (usually a link to the company's own jobs site).  This ended up having the same unique id in two lists, which we then attempt to merge, resulting in duplicate instances of the identifier.

Comment: Thank you @JohnM.Wright the issue is fixed

Comment: When dealing with users, it's generally the case that anything can happen.